# how to communicate 2 instances inside the same VPC but different subnets (regions) using internal IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have 2 instances, 1 VPC and 2 subnets each one in different region.

1 instance has a public IP, the other one just have internal IP. I want the 2 instances to communicate with each other using their internal IP.

How can I achieve this?

**--Edit**

**instances**

name: instance-a

zone: us-central1-a

network: testing

network tags: testing-allow-internal testing-allow-ssh

internal ip: 10.10.0.2

external ip: none

---

name: instance-b

zone: northamerica-northeast1-a

network: testing

network tags: testing-allow-internal testing-allow-ssh

internal ip: 10.20.0.2

external ip: yes

---

**vpc**

name: testing

Dynamic routing mode: global

---

**subnets**

name: testing

region: us-central1

IP address ranges: 10.10.0.0/15

gateway: 10.10.0.1

Private Google Access: On

---

name: testing

region: northamerica-northeast1

IP address ranges: 10.20.0.0/15

gateway: 10.20.0.1

Private Google Access: On

---

**Firewall Rules**

name: testing-allow-internal

type: Ingress

targets: Apply to all

filters: IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0

protocols / ports: all

action: Allow

priority: 65534

network: testing

---

name: testing-ssh

type: Ingress

targets: Apply to all

filters: IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0

protocols / ports: tcp:22

action: Allow

priority: 65534

network: testing

Now, what I am trying to achieve:
connect from local to instance-b via ssh usinf external IP. I just want instance-b to connect to instance-a via ssh using internal IP ie: ssh user@instance-b-external-ip >> ssh user@instance-a-internal-ip

I can ping, but when I try to connect to instance-a from instance-b using internal-ip via ssh, it always say permission denied.

---

**New Edit SSH**

I connect to instance-b using external-ip ie: ssh user@externalip. Inside **instance-b** i create ssh keys using the following command

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/instance_b
```

the pub key and private key

> public key: instance_b.pub

> private key: instance_b

I add the public key to the **SSH KEYS** using GUI

then I connect as usual ssh user@10.10.0.2

```
The authenticity of host '10.10.0.2 (10.10.0.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:iA1FfVyXM1234OsIy424ElVLnjGg2tMuSmdbsGWGLSs.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.10.0.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
user@10.10.0.2: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I get **permission denied**

**BUT** if I use the following command:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/instance-b user@10.10.0.2
```

I can connect. Why??

---

If I am missing anything, please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: Use private IP and Boom, it works!

Comment: 1) If you want to connect to instances in the same VPC, then use private IP addresses. Compute instances do not have public IP addresses. Public IP addresses are assigned to a special One-to-One NAT that forwards public traffic to the VPC private IP address.

Comment: 2) Your question shows two firewall rules. The rule **testing-allow-internal** provides public Internet access. Your question does not show the **network tags** assigned to the instance. The network tags affect which rules are applied to the network interface for the instance. Most likely that rule is not applied to your compute instances.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I do show the **network tags** and both instances have **network tags**: **testing-allow-internal** and **testing-allow-ssh**

Comment: However, are you using the private IP address?

Comment: Note: Do not set this **targets: Apply to all**. You should assign firewall rules selectively. The CIDR 0.0.0.0/0 allows the entire Internet to access your compute instances that have a public IP address.

Comment: from instance-b I created ssh keys and added the pub key to the instance-a ssh-keys then I try to connect to instance-a from instance-b using ssh. ie: ssh user@10.10.0.2

Comment: Note: I just noticed the permission denied for SSH. That is **not** a firewall problem. That is an SSH key or permission problem.

Comment: I suspected it was something about ssh and not GCP. But the curious thing is that if I set an external IP to instance-a I can connect from local, but not from instance-b, how's that even possible?

Comment: Edit your question with details on how you configure SSH key authorization and the exact command that you used. You must specify the SSH key unless you have configured **.ssh/config** with **Host** confirmation information.

Comment: Because you are most likely using different SSH keys or usernames. However, you must specify the exact command used. Details make all the difference.

Comment: Review how to read the SSH server log files. That will tell you exactly why a client cannot log in.

Comment: You state **I add the public key to the SSH KEYS using GUI**. To which instance did you add the public key? If you are connecting from instance_a to instance_b, instance_a must use the SSH private key and instance_b must have the public key configured in known_hosts for that usrname.

Comment: I am connecting from **instance-b** to **instance-a**, so I added **instance-b** pub key in **instance-a** by using **SSH KEYS** from **GUI**

Comment: Then review the SSH server logs to determine why the private key does not work. Also, verify that the public key is present in ~/.ssh/known_hosts in instance_a for the username you are using to connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VPC subnets within the same VPC can communicate with each other. The VPC Firewall rule **default-allow-internal** allows all TCP, UDP, and ICMP traffic between resources within the same VPC.

The key is to use the internal (private) IP address.

Comment: appreciate your response, I just can't connect, I may be missing a firewall rule or something, not sure. I ping the remote instance and nothing.

Comment: @iamnewbie - **I cannot connect** is not a good problem statement. Edit your question with details such as a) how are you connecting (the exact command)? b) what is the response/error? c) What are the VPC Firewall rules that you have configured? Given my statement that services within the same VPC can communicate, add details on what you have configured or modified since you created the project.

Comment: I updated the question. Just hope is clear enough. Thanks

Comment: edited again with SSH as you requested